# Import from Excel Spreadsheet works in IE6 not IE8

Tags: 2007, list, excel, import

I'm having an issue in **SharePoint 2007** in **IE 8** where, when creating a new List using  Excel Spreadsheet Import, I get redirected to a **403 error**.  This feature works in IE 6 but not IE 8.  Can anyone provide a solution to this?  I can imagine I should probably check the ULS logs also...  Also, I've already tried repairing Office 2007 as indicated (by answer) on several MSDN forums.  This didn't work.

*@Micro$oft: This is probably the first time in my life IE 6 has actually did something right.*

Comment: oh, I feel some `tumbleweed` rolling by on this one...

Comment: What if you put IE8 in IE7 compatibility mode?

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this?